# How to design client side data and business layers

Tags: javascript, architecture

We are designing an enterprise application.

We are looking for ideas to our **client side** design (maybe already existing lib, books, design patterns, experience) for managing the data and the business layer in a decoupled way from the chosen framework that will finally render the DOM (Angular, React, etc.). From our experience we are aiming now to write the business in pure JavaScript and not on top of a specific framework so we can be more flexible and independent.

Some notices:

- The data/entities can be shared between different components. Each component can use the data in its own way, depending on the business logic.
- The data/entities may be refreshed several time.

Comment: Where are you going to store entities? Also, what's the nature of your application?

Comment: We think to store the entities in local storage (maybe using https://github.com/js-data/js-data to manage the data). The application is Enterprise application and we have several pages that share the some data in different ways.

Comment: Will you have any backend persistent data store behind it? It seems super dangerous to have business logic and storage on client side from security perspective for an enterprise application